# Use list of strings elements as arrays

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a list of strings:

```
list1 = ['array1', 'array2', 'array3']
```

whose elements I would like to use as names of other lists, like (as conceptual example):

```
list1[0] = [1, 2, 3]
```

I know this assignation does not make any sense, but it is only to show what I need.
I have looked for this a lot but didn't find a handy example. If I understood properly, this is not the right way to do it, and better is to use `dictionaries`. But, I never used dictionaries yet, so I would need some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aDict = { name: 42 for name in list1 }
```

This gives you:

```
{'array3': 42, 'array2': 42, 'array1': 42}
```

If you wanted it ordered:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
aDict = OrderedDict((name, 42) for name in list1)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I try `aDict = { name: [] for name in list1 }`, when I `print adict` the order of the elements is not the same as in `list1`, why?

Comment: Because dictionaries are not ordered. They use hash tables to make lookups by name fast instead. If you want to preserve order there is an OrderedDict subclass, but this is rarely necessary.

Comment: Ok, and how would be `OrderedDict` used in this case, if I want to print `aDict` with the original order?

Comment: @Py-ser: I updated my answer to include OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary:

```
list1 = {'array1': [0, 1, 2], 'array2': [0, 3], 'array3': [1]}
```

and then access it like this:

```
list1['array1'] # output is [0, 1, 2]
```

To dynamically populate your dictionary:

```
list1 = {'array1': []}
list1['array1'].append(1)
```

Comment: I don't know the content of the lists when I define my dictionary!

Comment: @Py-ser I have added another code snippet. Treat everything that you dereference from the dictionary by key as a list because that's what it is in your case.

Comment: Thanks! So why can't I just `print array1` ?

Comment: @Py-ser Because it's contained in the dictionary, so you have to do print list1['array1']

Answer (score 1):

You can do What you want with `exec` like this :

```
list1 = ['array1', 'array2', 'array3']
x=list1[1]    
exec("%s = %d" % (x,2))
print array2
```

so result is :
`2`

**But never use `exec` when you can use something much safer like dictionary, it can be dangerous !**